# Add multiple $data references to require property in JSON Schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, ajv, jsonpointer

I have an array `filters-detail` with objects in it. These objects should include the values of the other properties `filters-applied` and `applied-second`. I use **AJV** and tried to use two `$data` objects but it fails.

```json
{
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "filters-applied": {
      "type": "array",
      "uniqueItems": true,
      "items": {
        "type": "string",
        "maxLength": 255
      }
    },
    "applied-second": {
      "type": "array",
      "uniqueItems": true,
      "items": {
        "type": "string",
        "maxLength": 255
      }
    },
    "filters-detail": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": [
          {
            "$data": "2/filters-applied"
          },
          {
            "$data": "2/applied-second"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example data that should be valid:

```json
{
  "filters-applied": ["color", "size"],
  "applied-second": ["brand"],
  "filters-detail": [{ color: ["red", "blue"], size: "XS", brand: "Boss" }],
}
```

I managed to get only one requirement working:

```json
"filters-detail": {
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "required": {
      "$data": "2/filters-applied"
    }
  }
}
```

Noticeable are the missing `[]`, but I don't know how to leave them and add two objects to `required` without violating against the JSON structure.

I need to depend on **two** other properties.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried using `allOf` to merge the schema properties?

Comment: @AbhikBanerjee You mean with `"required": { "allOf": [ { "$data": "2/filters-applied" }, { "$data": "2/applied-second" } ] }` ? Unfortunately this doesn't work either